# Laravel: ORM independant Repository pattern

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, orm, repository-pattern

I stumbled upon different articles about implementing Repository pattern in Laravel and all of them making me confused. Everyone of them is putting their weight on **"keeping it ORM independent"** but no one is actually showing the example code.

I am here with my repository sample structure which I believe is not ORM independent in a way. But I need it with **REAL REPOSITORY PATTERN** solution where I can change the ORM from `Eloquent` model to something else like *Doctrine*. And keep the **Business logic** separate some way so i no need to change it. currently my Business logic lies in Repository (not recommended i think.)

Basic Questions:

1. My repository, uses Eloquent method name inside it which will not be there if i change the ORM. `$this->model = $shops;`
2. In Controllers and Blade templates what we are playing with is `Collections` of `Eloquent Model`. How should we handle them if we change the ORM?
3. Where to put create/delete methods if not in repository.

> Please don't just use `Domain Object` word because I am tired of
>   understanding it without an coded example. It will be highly
>   appreciated if you try to explain [Domain object] using a real code
>   example by modifying this. [How to return it in controller and use it
>   in Blade]

**Interface:**

```
<?php

namespace Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Repository\Contract;

interface ShopsRepository {    
    public function getall();
    public function create($data);
    public function update($id, $data);
    public function delete($id);
}
```

**Eloquent:**

```
<?php

namespace Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Repository\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Repository\Contract\ShopsRepository;
use Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Shops;

class ShopsEloquent implements ShopsRepository
{

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Shops $shops)
    {
        $this->model = $shops;
    }

    public function getall()
    {
        return $this->model::with('shopadmin')->get();
    }

    public function create($data)
    {        
        $this->model::create($data);
    }

    public function update($id, $data)
    {
       $this->model::findOrFail($id)->update($data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->model::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    }    
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Modules\ShopOwner\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Repository\Contract\ShopsRepository;
use Modules\ShopOwner\Entities\Shops;
use Validator;

class ShopsController extends Controller
{
    protected $shops;    

    public function __construct(ShopsRepository $shops)
    {
        $this->shops = $shops;   
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $shops = $this->shops->getall();

        return view('shopowner::shops.list', compact('shops'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();      

        $this->shops->create($data);

        return redirect()->route('SO.shops.index')->with('success', __('shopowner::shops.create_success'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {        
        $data = $request->all();

        $this->shops->update($id, $data);

        return redirect()->route('SO.shops.index')->with('success', __('shopowner::shops.update_success'));
    }   

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->shops->delete($id);

        return redirect()->route('SO.shops.index')->with('success', __('shopowner::shops.remove_success'));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base repository first. then extend this repository. Try this way. It may help you

```
interface BaseRepository{    
    public function getall();
    public function create($data);
    public function update($id, $data);
    public function delete($id);
}


class BaseEloquent implements BaseRepository{
    protected $model;

    public function getall(){
        return $this->model->get();
    }

    ....
    ....

}


interface ShopsRepository extends BaseRepository{

}

class ShopsEloquent extends BaseEloquent implements ShopsRepository{

    public function __construct(Shops $shops){
            $this->model = $shops;
    }

    public function getall(){
        return $this->model::with('shopadmin')->get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how will it answer my 3 questions?